# Is there a safe way to convert Windows UTF-16 path(WCHAR* / wchar_t*) to ANSI path (char*)?

Tags: c, windows, unicode, path, type-conversion

I am trying to use the below Tensorflow C API function to load a saved model.

```
TF_CAPI_EXPORT extern TF_Session* TF_LoadSessionFromSavedModel(
    const TF_SessionOptions* session_options, const TF_Buffer* run_options,
    const char* export_dir, const char* const* tags, int tags_len,
    TF_Graph* graph, TF_Buffer* meta_graph_def, TF_Status* status);
```

The issue is, the function expects a path`export_dir` in `char *`. However, Windows system path is in a WCHAR(wchar_t) array and may have non-ANSI characters. I have tried simply convert the format using [wcstombs_s](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/wcstombs-s-wcstombs-s-l?view=msvc-170), but it seems this approach doesn't deal with unicode path well.

Here is my code:

```
// get current path in WCHAR array, then append '/model'
WCHAR curpath[MAX_PATH];
GetCurrentDirectory(MAX_PATH, curpath);
PathCombineW(this->model_path, curpath, TEXT("model"));

// convert path to 'char*'
unsigned int char_path_size = MAX_PATH * sizeof(WCHAR) / sizeof(char);
char *mb_path = (char*) malloc(char_path_size); // allocate a char array
wcstombs_s(nullptr, mb_path, char_path_size, this->model_path, char_path_size);

...

TF_LoadSessionFromSavedModel(sessionOpts, runOpts, mb_path, &tags, ntags, this->graph, nullptr, status);
```

The above code works fine if the path to the executable is

```
C:\Users\Alice\project\
```

but it wouldn't work if the path is

```
C:\Users\爱丽丝\project\
```

Comment: If you are converting Unicode to a specific codepage, you must make sure that codepage has the code points you are going to be using. What is the codepage for non-Unicode programs in your Windows?

Comment: How about converting the path to short form, and then convert to ANSI?

Comment: @GSerg I'm not sure, I'm looking for a way to make any UTF-16 path work with the function.

Comment: Looking at the TensorFlow source code, it appears to expect UTF8 strings.

Answer (score 0):

There is no guaranteed way to convert a UTF-16 string to a Windows code page because not all characters can be represented. The exceptions are `CP_UTF8` and `CP_UTF7`.

```
int size = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, widestring, -1, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
if (!size) error...
char* narrowstring = (char*) malloc(size);
if (!narrowstring) error...
WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, widestring, -1, narrowstring, size, NULL, NULL);
```

For this to work

A) The function has to expect UTF-8.

or

B) Run Windows 10/11 and [set the default codepage to UTF-8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/globalizing/use-utf8-code-page).